# Why spring beans are not created in jar files, but in class files

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I am using spring for some dependency injection via the annotations. The problem ist whenever I start the application and use the .jar ,created by gradle, in the classpath Im getting the following exception: "org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException"

But if the /build/classes/main/ is in the classpath the beans are created and no exception is thrown.

So the beans are created in the build/classes/main/ but not in the build/libs/*.jar

Comment: Do you scan packages with `classpath:org.mypackage` or `classpath*:org.mypackage`? The last one scans jars from classpath as well.

Comment: Thank you!!! I added the @ComponentScan annotation to the spring configuration class and now it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `@ComponentScan("classpath*:org.mypackage")` to let Spring scan jars as well.